# Creating alerts from changes at the item level in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to incorporate a check at the item line level when creating an invoice.  Basically if they are adding an item within a certain category (custitem8) i need an alert to pop up for the sales rep.

Not sure if this should be using fieldchanged or validateline.

Sorry Im not really a programmer and am learning on the job mostly by trial and error.  Thanks for your help.

```
function ValidateLine(type)
{
    if (nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'custitem8') = 'Order in Only - Not For Trade Guide')
    {
        alert("Order In Only, Please contact Purchasing");
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggested code will not work, instead of using nlapiGetLineItemValue use nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue.

the code should look like this.

```
postSourcing(sublistId, fieldId) {
   if(sublistId == "item" && fieldId == "item") {
      var itemId = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue(sublistId, fieldId);
      var category = nlapiLookupField("item", itemId, "custitem8");

      if(category == "Order in Only - Not For Trade Guide") {
        alert("Order In Only, Please contact Purchasing");
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you just need an alert when the user selects a line Item? If so, I would suggest using `postSourcing(sublistId, fieldId)` (though using `validateLine(sublistId)` works just fine).

As for the actual function content, I'm assuming (based on the field ID) "custitem8" is a field on the Item record. If so, you will have to load the field from the Item record first.

Based on my understanding of your post, I would go about it like this:

```
postSourcing(sublistId, fieldId) {
   if(sublistId == "item" && fieldId == "item") {
      var itemId = nlapiGetLineItemValue("item", "item");
      var category = nlapiLookupField("item", itemId, "custitem8");

      if(category == "Order in Only - Not For Trade Guide") {
        alert("Order In Only, Please contact Purchasing");
      }
   }
}
```

And just a note, I don't really know the data type of the "custitem8" field, so I'm just assuming it's a free-form text field.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help however am still having a few problems.  
custitem8 is indeed an item field however it is list/record field the id of 'order in only...' is 9 so I have tried incorporating that in the function wiht/without quotations however I am having no luck.  

Netsuite is coming up with the error msg 
"SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT
nlapiLookupField: Missing a required argument: id"
any suggestions on what I should be doing?
Thanks again.